# phpMyAdmin error: Cannot return a ResultSet in the Given Context in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Please have a look at the code below:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE `mostPopular`
CREATE PROCEDURE `mostPopular`()
BEGIN
DROP view if exists mostRec;
create view mostRec as select count(*) as ord,course_code from cms.courses_viewed group by course_code;
select course_name from course join mostRec on course.course_code=mostRec.course_code order by ord desc;
END
```

This code works in Mysql Workbench but it does not work in phpMyadmin.
It prints "`Cannot return a ResultSet in the Given Context in mysql`". Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is because the PMA doesn't use [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you can test it by making a php script that executes this procedure using the mentioned function